# Как решить проблему с версткой?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Прошу Вашей помощи в верстке. Вот как должно быть (на многих страницах [сайта](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua) все ок):

```
<img src="http://i66.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1006/9d/aaf79d32165a0611ddaf1768206df59d.png" border="0">
```

А на некоторых страницах [сайта](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/index.php/lechenie-narkomanii) верстка съезжает, хотя стили используется на всех страницах одинаковые:

```
<img src="http://i64.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1006/2c/8b7dbe6daa53d18d8debc0ae1857cf2c.png" border="0">
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти проблему в верстке и стилях и решить ее. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Укажите поточнее, в каком именно элементе проблема, чтобы меньше тратили времени на поиск в коде.

Comment: @Дмитрий Клименко, я думаю, проблема в этих элементах:
 
    #vt_main_com,.vt_component_inside{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    width:70%;
    }
    .contentwidthr{
    width:100%
    }

Answer (score 1):

У Вас где-то перекрываются стили. Поставьте в components.css:4 !important в двух местах.

```
#vt_main_com, .vt_component_inside {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 70% !important;
}
```

inline:27

```
.contentwidthr {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```